# requests segfaults when embedded as wsgi, but not standalone

Tags: python, apache, python-requests, wsgi

```
import sys
import os
import logging

# need to add environment to apache's path for includes
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../../")))
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../")))
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".")))
# likewise add cherrypy/other modules
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/"))

import requests
response = requests.get('http://www.google.com').text
```

Using Python 2.7.6, requests 2.7.0, and Apache under MAMP 3.0, the above code crashes. A quick look through the code using winpdb seems to suggest that actually trying to open an internet connection is what is crashing the Python process. The Apache log is not very helpful, only saying

```
[notice] child pid 18879 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

While my full code uses Cherrypy 3.8 to provide the WSGI portion of the framework, I feel that it is irrelevant to the problem at hand.

Is this some known problem with requests+apache, or is it some other problem? Python crashing without any comments makes it hard for me to even think of a way to start solving this issue.

**EDIT**: Using pdb, I found that the program segfaults on line 1421 of urllib.py in the python standard library.

```
proxy_settings = _get_proxy_settings()
```

where _get_proxy_settings comes from _scproxy.

I still have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a platform-specific bug for my version of MacOS.